# Need Help: Model is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So what I'm doing is I have a rake task that everyday will decrease the days left on a subscription. Here is the rake task:

```
namespace :delete do
  desc 'Remove a day for premium subscription days left'
  task :premium_subscription_remove => :environment do
    PremiumSubscription.find_each do | premium_subscription| 
        premium_subscription.premium_subscription_days_left -= 1
        premium_subscription.save
    end
  end
end
```

This rake task will count down the days left on the subscription. Now I created a new model that will handle the days left once it hit zero. Once it hit zero the code will cause the subscription to auto renew. Here is the code for the renewal:

```
  def self.renew_premium_subscription(user, premium_subscribe)
    if premium_subscribe.premium_subscription_days_left <= 0
      user.premium_subscriptions.where(:premium_subscribe_id => premium_subscribe.id).destroy_all
      if user.points >= premium_subscribe.premium_subscription_cost
        user.premium_subscriptions.where(:premium_subscribe_id => premium_subscribe.id).first_or_create
        user.points = user.points - premium_subscribe.premium_subscription_cost
        user.save
      end
    end
  end
```

The problem I am having is that the premium_subscription_days_left is at negative two and the renew_premium_subscription has never been acted. I tried putting in random letters and the model hasn't givin an error. How does the model get acted upon inorder for the renewal? I have put code in the controller:

```
  def renew_subscription
    PremiumSubscription.renew_premium_subscription(current_user, @user)
  end
```

But that hasn't worked at all. If anybody knows how to get this thing working it will be great. Thank you for the help : )

edit: Tried putting the update function inside of the rake task but that did not work at all.

edit 2: No such luck on getting this fixed. Anybody have a clue?

edit 3: So i though about something, is there a way to automatically call a model class. I just need to get this thing working.

Here is an outline of what I did:

1. Created a rake task. This rake task will be called with whenever to count down to zero.
2. I created a model in the premiumSubscription model that says when it hits zero it will either update the subscription or destroy it.
3. I have set the count down to zero, refreshed the page but the subscription isn't updated or destroyed.

edit 4: So I learned that the controller needs to be triggered by a route. Is there any way to trigger this code when the page loads?

Comment: Have you tried making a stopping point for the variable..? The code you show will just keep subtracting because it's never told to stop when it hits 0

Comment: The code in the rake task is run once a day. What I am trying to do is once it hit's zero it triggers the model code and controller shown here. However it's on zero (and stays at zero for the duration of the day) but it still never triggers the model.

Comment: Awh, misread it, my apologies.

Comment: It's okay, thank you for trying to help : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of notes:

`user.save`

This can fail. If `save` is unsuccessful it will return `false`. Your method does not test the return value, so an unsuccessful save will go unnoticed -- nothing is written to the log file, no error is raised, nada. Either check the result of `save` or call `save!`, which will raise an exception.

`premium_subscription.premium_subscription_days_left -= 1`

You might have a good reason for storing this value, but you should also consider storing the start date (or the expiration date) instead, and calculating the days left given the current date. Decrementing "days left" requires that the cron job runs when it is supposed to ... if it misses a day, the count will be off.

Comment: Thank you... I didn't think about the cron job failing. I'll update that into the code. Now do you know why the renew_premium_subscription isn't working? I think it's correct with the code but it's never called. Again, thank you for the help  : )

Comment: Are you sure that it isn't called? Or is it called and doesn't do what you expect?

Comment: I am pretty sure it's not being called. I put in a simple update that will change the day's left to 300000 but in the database it is still -2.

Comment: Are you checking the return value from `save`?

Comment: I tried typing a bunch of random characters under the controller renew subscription and it didn't check to see if it was a correct method or anything.

Comment: Wait, I thought we were talking about rake tasks. How does the controller fit into this? What are you doing to kick off this process?

Comment: Sorry, the rake process counts down the days. I have a method in my controller that says once the count down is zero then it will renew or cancel the subscription.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the steps you are taking so that we understand what is going on. This has some excellent advice: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I added a list at the end of what I've done. Hopefully it's a little more clear. Sorry about that.